# Finding the power of a number without a library pow function

Tags: algorithms

I am solving a problem that involves finding a `pow(x, n)` without using a `pow` library function.

Following is the algorithm that works (apart from negative `n` and some edge cases) but trying to understand the math logic behind it.

```
2^5 -> x = 2, n = 5 (101)
```

The idea is to multiply the answer with `2 ^ (2 ^ i)` such that `i` is ith bit of the exponent `n`.

So we can say: `2^5 = 2 ^ (2 ^ 0) * 2 ^ (2 ^ 2)`. Means: we need to multiply the answer with when the ith bit is 0, and 2 (set bits in `101`)

```
n = 101, i = 0: ans = 2 * 1 = 2, x = 2 * 2 = 2 ^ 2 = 4
n = 010, i = 1: ans = 2, x = 4 * 4 = 2 ^ (2 ^ 2) = 16
n = 001, i = 2: ans = 2 * 16 = 32, x = 16 * 16 === 2 ^ (2 ^ 0) * 2 ^ (2 ^ 2)
```

This seems to work however the following example doesn't

```
2^8 -> x = 2, n = 8 (1000)
```

So we can say: `2^8 = 2 ^ 4 * 2 ^ 4 == 2 ^ (2 ^ 2) * 2 ^ (2 ^ 2)`. Means: we need to multiply the answer with when the ith bit is 2, and 2, however there's only ONE set bit at i = 3.

The algo

```
  double foo()
  {
    double ret = 1;
            
    while (n)
    {
        if (n & 1) 
        {
            ret *= x;
        }
        
        x *= x;
        n >>= 1;
        
    }
  
      return ret;
   }
```

also is the time complexity going to be O(logN)?

Comment: What's $N$? If $N=n$ and you are using the RAM model with uniform costs the time will be $O(\log N)$. Also $n$ is undefined in your code.

Comment: That's a procedure, not an algo[rithm]: if *n* is negative it could loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

Let $k$ be the number of binary digits of $n$ and let $n_i$ denote the $i$-th least significant digit in the binary representation of $n$, counting from $1$.

$$n = \sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i 2^{i-1}$$

Therefore:
$x^n = x^{\sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i 2^{i-1}} = \prod_{i=1}^{k} x^{n_i 2^{i-1}}$.

At the beginning of the $j$-th iteration of the algorithm `x` is equal to $x^{2^{j-1}}$ and `res` is equal to $\prod_{i=1}^{j-1} x^{n_i 2^{i-1}}$.

At the end of the $j$-th iteration of the algorithm:

- `res` is equal to $\prod_{i=1}^{j} x^{n_i 2^{i-1}}$, which is obtained by multiplying
  `x` with the current value of `res` when $n_j=1$. This the same as unconditionally performing the following product:
  $$
  x^{n_j  2^{j-1}} \cdot\prod_{i=1}^{j-1} x^{n_i 2^{i-1}}.
  $$
- `x` is equal to $x^{2^j}$ and is obtained by multiplying `x` with itself, i.e., $x^{2^j} = x^{2^{j-1}} \cdot x^{2^{j-1}}$.

Comment: I am trying to understand the way `2^n` could be broken down into components that align well with the algorithm. For 2^8, j = 3 `2^8 = 2^4 * 2^4 = 2^(2^2) * 2^(2^2)`. Works, but how do you break down `2^6`? what's `j`? it will be a decimal with this logic

Comment: $2^6 = 2^4 \cdot 2^2$, so `res` gets multiplies by $2^2$ and $2^4$ in the third and fifth iteration, respectively. $j$ is always an integer. It is always between $1$ and $k$, and represents the iteration number in the algorithm.

Comment: yes but you mentioned `x^2^j = x^2^(j-1) . x^2^(j-1)`. You don't break `2^6` further down?

Comment: $6$ is not of the form $2^j$. The values that `x` will have during the algorithm are $x,x^2,x^4,x^8,x^{16},\dots$. The final value of `res` is computed as $(1\cdot x^2) \cdot x^4$ (or $(1\cdot x^{2^1})\cdot x^{2^2}$ if you wish). The product $1\cdot x^2$ happens in the `if` block at the beginning of the 2nd iteration ($j=2$), when `x` is equal to $x^2=x^{2^1}=x^{2^{j-1}}$. The product of the result of this multiplication with $x^4$ happens in the 3rd iteration ($j=3$), when `x` is equal to $x^4 = x^{2^2}=x^{2^{j-1}}$. (Sorry, the iteration numbers in the previous comment were wrong).

Comment: I am still trying to relate to the algo that involves multiplying `x` with `res` when the LSb is 1. Initially I thought it would be `j` in `2^(2^(j-1))` but it works for `2^5 = 2^4*2^1 = 2^(2^2) * 2^(2^0)` (set bits at i=2, i=0) but doesn't for `2^8 = 2^4*2^4 = 2^(2^2) * 2^(2^2)`. (set bit is NOT at i=2,i=2)

Answer (score 0):

Calculating powers with integer exponents: You use these formulas: x^0 = 1. x^(k+1) = x^k * x. x^(2k) = (x^k)^2. x^(-k) = 1 / x^k.

Then you implement via recursion:

```
if (k == 0) return 1.0;
if (k < 0) return 1.0 / myPower (x, -k);
if (k % 2 == 1) return myPower (x, k-1) * x;
/* if (k % 2 == 0) */ { tmp = myPower (x, k/2); return tmp * tmp; }
```

That may be a bit slow due to recursion so you then refactor your code to make it fast.

Comment: Other than handling the problem with n<0 and other bugs, is that method actually faster than the way the original was trying to do it?